# the expression you entered contain invalid syntax in access query

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make a query. I don't type anything. I use only every formula by clicking in built-in function of access, but I get this popup error

[image]

Comment: You have incorrect quotation blocks.  Please past the code into your code as well as the image.  Trimming the image down and showing it in your post would also be a nice touch.

Comment: Hi&Thanks  IdKioskEjraN: IIf( [IdKioskEjra2] = [IdKioskEjra]  ؛ "Ok"؛ "NoK")

Comment: This problem repeat for every function that contain this character ؛
such as mid  IdKioskEjraN:  Mid( [IdKioskEjra2]  ؛ 2؛ 4)

Comment: That code should be in your post not in the comments.  The functions should have commas between parameters not `؛ `.

Comment: Please post the SQL version of your query as text into body of your post. See SQL view.

Answer (score 0):

The function iif requires the condition, iftrue, and iffalse to be separated with a comma, not a colon. Makr it look like this:

Iif(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse)